# "Type does not contain a definition for class" error but it TOTALLY does

Tags: c#

I'm working in a C# project using the `Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Messaging.dll`.  I have a method I call which enumerates a bunch of info I need to know about a device and formats it into a format Configuration Manager can work with.  I end up with a `Collection<InventoryReportBodyElement>` objects, which are defined like this:

```
namespace Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Messaging.Messages
{
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InventoryInstance))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ProductInfo))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InventoryInstanceGeneric))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(StateMessage))]
    public class InventoryReportBodyElement
    {
        public InventoryReportBodyElement();
    }
}
```

Here is where I am very confused.  I need to edit the properties of one of the items in my collection but when I try to use Linq method syntax in to select the right entity, I get this compiler error:

```
InventoryReportBodyElement OSClass = ddrMessage.DdrInstances.Where(m => m.Class == "CCM_DiscoveryData");
```

Class is highlighted with:

> InventoryReportBodyElement' does not contain a definition for 'Class'
>   and no accessible extension method 'Class' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'InventoryReportBodyElement' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

However, when I am debugging...I totally see all of properties, including the class name I want to use to filter down to the right item.  If I comment out my select code and step through each item in the collection, I can see the properties I need in the Locals Window.

```
foreach (InventoryReportBodyElement Record in ddrMessage.DdrInstances)
        {
        //InventoryReportBodyElement OSClass = ddrMessage.DdrInstances.Where(m => m.Class == "CCM_DiscoveryData");                    
        Debug.WriteLine(Record.ToString());
        }
```

[image]

What am I missing here?  I have the dll referenced...the items are there when the code runs.  Why the compiler errors?

Comment: well, first of all, there is no body for your `InventoryReportBodyElement` constructor. Also, there is no `public string Class { get; }` property. In your `foreach` loop, can you check the value of `Record.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: Your error is about `InventoryReportBodyElement`, while in the debug info you can see `Class` is a property of `InventoryInstance`, see the value of record in the first line in image, maybe the first class from the attributes is being used as the default conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in the debugger doesn't count because everything you see in the debugger exists only at runtime. The compiler doesn't know what's going to be in there at runtime except that it's going to be an instance of `InventoryReportBodyElement` (or an instance of a subclass). The only thing the compiler can see is your class definition and it definitely does not contain a member called `Class`.

It appears that the runtime type of the instance is actually `InventoryInstance` which is what actually defines a `Class` property. In which case you should probably be filtering the collection using `OfType`:

```
ddrMessage.DdrInstances.OfType<InventoryInstance>().Where(m => m.Class == "CCM_DiscoveryData");
```

Comment: I see that this works but I don't really know why it does. Why is OfType needed?

Comment: @FoxDeploy `OfType` attempts to cast each item to the specified type and only provides items where the cast succeeds. The compiler then knows all the items that `Where` sees will definitely be of type `InventoryInstance`, which has a property called `Class`.